# Unable to write parentheses in Dreamweaver script

Tags: javascript, html, dreamweaver

I have just installed Dreamweaver CC on my new laptop. 
However, when I want to use any kind of parentheses or brackets in the script, it wont write it in the code. 
So basically:

```
<script>
window.alert(msg)
</script>
```

I cant write () signs, nor [], {}.

What can be the problem?
Thank you!

Comment: A helpful hint without any form of judgement: Uninstall it. Dreamweaver is a really bad way to learn coding and build applications.

Comment: I forgot to mention: when I am out of the script, and just simply in the html code, i can use them.

Comment: As is being said above, it would be probably be better to use an editor like Sublime Text, Atom or Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Even Notepad++ would be better than Dreamweaver. Trust me, I spent a number of months learning how to use Dreamweaver and I would have gotten much further along if I had just started writing code without it.

Comment: Thank you all for the advises but I am not using it for learning :) I use it for my job, and use it because it has great features, like automatic close tag ect, and I am used to it.

Comment: @oko2 Most editors have great features like automatic close tag and more.